# C/GTK+ GTK_IS_PROGESSBAR failed

Tags: c, gtk

I have a `main.c` file where a progress bar is created and then it will be updated by `other.c` file.

Inside the `main.c` file i have this:

```
static void
a_func (    GtkWidget *dialog,
        struct widget_t *Widget,
        gint mode)
{

....
....

Widget->pBar = gtk_progress_bar_new ();

....
....
}
```

which create and run a dialog. When OK is pushed `my_func (Widget);` will be called.

Inside the `other.c` file i have this:

```
static gboolean
fill (gpointer data)
{
    GtkWidget *bar = data;

    gtk_progress_bar_pulse (GTK_PROGRESS_BAR (bar));

    return TRUE;
}

gint my_func (struct mystruct_t *Widget){

....
....

gtk_progress_bar_pulse (GTK_PROGRESS_BAR (Widget->pBar));

g_timeout_add (100, fill, GTK_PROGRESS_BAR (Widget->pBar));

while (gtk_events_pending ())
   gtk_main_iteration ();

....
....
}
```

The problem is that i'm getting this error:

```
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkProgressBar'

Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_progress_bar_pulse: assertion 'GTK_IS_PROGRESS_BAR (pbar)' failed
```

**EDIT 1:**

This is a compilable example: https://gist.github.com/polslinux/96e7b18176ac66e50ee1

**EDIT 2:**

This is a simple workflow graph: http://it.tinypic.com/r/316us0y/8

Comment: Have you tried any debugging yet? Like checking with debug-prints that your initialization actually happens before the  gtk_progress_bar_pulse() call? Could also check that the struct pointer is actually the same one in both cases -- it seems to be of different type at least...

Comment: @jku I tried using g_print("%p", Widget->pBar) on `main.c` and `other.c` and the address is always the same :-/ The strangest thing is that the progress bar is updated with the first call inside `my_func`. The errors come from the `fill` function...

Comment: Can you provide a minimal _compilable_ example that does reproduce your issue. To me it is not clear which line actually produces the warning.

Comment: @drahnr added link to a compilable example into the question :)

Comment: Can you condense it some more. I am pretty sure you can rip of half that code.

Comment: @drahnr i've simplied the gist :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can not work:

```
    crypt_file (Widget);
    gtk_widget_destroy (dialog);
```

You add a `GSource` to your mainloop which modifies `Widget->pBar` **but you never remove it**. On the other hand you destroy the dialog (and thus also `pBar` itself as it is part of the widget sub-tree) which in turn renders `Widget->pBar` useless/makes it a dangling pointer.

---

Things you did not ask for (excuse the direct approach)

- Your variable names are crappy at best, upper lower case, calling things `Widget` which are no widgets but mere structs.
- Make sure you do not split into callbacks and other C functions. That will end up totally messy as your project grows.
- Try to go for object-orientation. Create a `GObject` derived klass which handles the mess internally instead of passing translucent structs around.

Comment: Thx for your answer and for your suggestions, they are always welcome:) i didn't understand some things: 1) what do you mean with "but you never remove it"? 2) i thought that CamelCase was a good convention for writing variables or am i wrong? What is a better method? 3) yes, `Widget` is not a good name, i'm gonna changing it (do you know a good convention for writing structs name in C?) 4) what do you mean with "Make sure you do not split into callbacks and other C functions"? 5) i gonna read c-gobject, i never thought to use it. Thanks for all :)

Comment: `g_timeout_add` adds a `GSource` to the mainloop, you can remove it by its id or by returning `FALSE`/`G_SOURCE_REMOVE` – but you are not doing any of those two. In C (especially in the glib/gnome context) camel case is used for typedef'd structs (also the stackoverflow highlighting thinks it is a type, as seen in my post). Use all down characters for variable/member names possibly with underscore. There are plenty __very__ old gtk projects which come with two C files. One for callbacks and one for the rest. It sucks, it is 90s C style not 2k14. Strongly discouraged.

Comment: Beware that the GObject system is not easy to grasp at the beginning, but it really allows you to do fancy things. https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/ If you really need intermediate structs for the mere transfer of pointers to widgets, use some obvious prefix like `TransferContainer` (or an abbreviation of that) but how to name those is really personal taste (as long as they are not misleading).

Comment: thanks a lot :) i will also look for gthread (so {maybe} i can avoid gobject for now)